# ElasticSearch - string concat aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, concatenation

I've got the following simple mapping:

```
"element": {
  "dynamic": "false",
  "properties": {
    "id": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
    "group": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
    "type": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
  }
}
```

Which basically is a way to store `Group` object:

```
{
  id : "...",
  elements : [
    {id: "...", type: "..."},
    ...
    {id: "...", type: "..."}
  ] 
}
```

I want to find how many different groups exist sharing the same set of element types (ordered, including repetitions).

An obvious solution would be to change the schema to:

```
"element": {
  "dynamic": "false",
  "properties": {
    "group": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
    "concatenated_list_of_types": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
  }
}
```

But, due to the requirements, we need to be able to exclude some types from group by (aggregation) :(

All fields of the document are mongo ids, so in SQL I would do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), concat_value FROM (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(type_id), group_id 
    FROM table
    WHERE type_id != 'some_filtered_out_type_id' 
    GROUP BY group_id
) T GROUP BY concat_value
```

In Elastic with given mapping it's really easy to filter out, its also not a problem to count assuming we have a concated value. Needless to say, sum aggregation does not work for strings.

How can I get this working? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem with [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) and by changing the mapping.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "group": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "elements": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There are still some issues with duplicate elements in array (ScriptDocValues.Strings) for some reason strips out dups, but here's an aggregation that counts by string concat:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "path": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "map_script": "key = doc['elements'].join('-'); _agg[key] = _agg[key] ? _agg[key] + 1 : 1",
        "combine_script": "_agg",
        "reduce_script": "_aggs.collectMany { it.entrySet() }.inject( [:] ) { result, e -> result << [ (e.key):e.value + ( result[ e.key ] ?: 0 ) ]}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result would be as follows:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "path" : {
      "value" : {
        "5639abfb5cba47087e8b457e" : 362,
        "568bfc495cba47fc308b4567" : 3695,
        "5666d9d65cba47701c413c53" : 14,
        "5639abfb5cba47087e8b4571-5639abfb5cba47087e8b457b" : 1,
        "570eb97abe529e83498b473d" : 1
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about this issue? It looks similar to yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60650823/elasticsearch-mapping-the-result-of-collapse-do-operations-on-a-grouped-docume