# ElasticSearch mapping the result of collapse / do operations on a grouped documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

There is a list of conversations and every conversation has a list of messages. Every message has different fields and an `action` field. We need to consider that in the first messages of the conversation there is used the action `A`, after a few messages there is used action `A.1` and after a while `A.1.1` and so on (there is a list of chatbot intents).

Grouping the messages actions of a conversation will be something like: `A > A > A > A.1 > A > A.1 > A.1.1 ...`

**Problem:**

I need to create a report using ElasticSearch that will return the `actions group` of every conversation; next, I need to group the similar `actions groups` adding a count; in the end will result in a `Map<actionsGroup, count>` as `'A > A.1 > A > A.1 > A.1.1', 3`.

Constructing the `actions group` I need to eliminate every group of duplicates; Instead of `A > A > A > A.1 > A > A.1 > A.1.1` I need to have `A > A.1 > A > A.1 > A.1.1`.

**Steps I started to do**:

```
{
   "collapse":{
      "field":"context.conversationId",
      "inner_hits":{
         "name":"logs",
         "size": 10000,
         "sort":[
            {
               "@timestamp":"asc"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "aggs":{
   },
}
```

**What I need next:**

1. I need to map the result of the collapse in a single result like `A > A.1 > A > A.1 > A.1.1`. I've seen that in the case or `aggr` is possible to use [scripts](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html) over the result and there is possible to create a list of actions like I need to have, but `aggr` is doing the operations over all messages, not only over the grouped messages that I have in collapse. It is there possible to use `aggr` inside collapse or a similar solution?
2. I need to group the resulted values(`A > A.1 > A > A.1 > A.1.1`) from all collapses, adding a count and resulting in the `Map<actionsGroup, count>`.

**Or:**

1. Group the conversations messages by `conversationId` field using `aggr` (I don't know how can I do this)
2. Use script to iterate all values and create the `actions group` for every conversation. (not sure if this is possible)
3. Use another `aggr` over all values and group the duplicates, returning `Map<actionsGroup, count>`.

Mappings:

```
"mappings":{
  "properties":{
     "@timestamp":{
        "type":"date",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
     }
     "context":{
        "properties":{
           "action":{
              "type":"keyword"
           },
           "conversationId":{
              "type":"keyword"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Sample documents of the conversations:

```
Conversation 1.
{
    "@timestamp": 1579632745000,
    "context": {
        "action": "A",
        "conversationId": "conv_id1",
    }
},
{
    "@timestamp": 1579632745001,
    "context": {
        "action": "A.1",
        "conversationId": "conv_id1",
    }
},
{
    "@timestamp": 1579632745002,
    "context": {
        "action": "A.1.1",
        "conversationId": "conv_id1",
    }
}

Conversation 2.
{
    "@timestamp": 1579632745000,
    "context": {
        "action": "A",
        "conversationId": "conv_id2",
    }
},
{
    "@timestamp": 1579632745001,
    "context": {
        "action": "A.1",
        "conversationId": "conv_id2",
    }
},
{
    "@timestamp": 1579632745002,
    "context": {
        "action": "A.1.1",
        "conversationId": "conv_id2",
    }
}

Conversation 3.
{
    "@timestamp": 1579632745000,
    "context": {
        "action": "B",
        "conversationId": "conv_id3",
    }
},
{
    "@timestamp": 1579632745001,
    "context": {
        "action": "B.1",
        "conversationId": "conv_id3",
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "A -> A.1 -> A.1.1": 2,
    "B -> B.1": 1
}
Something similar, having this or any other format.
```

Comment: You can use terms aggregation to group on a key. If you can add mapping, sample document and expected result, it will be easier to understand the problem

Comment: @jaspreetchahal I added some extra details.

Comment: Do you need count of conversationId ex convs1->2, convs2->1 ?  What is the role of action group here?

Comment: No. I need the count of conversations `actions group`. Like every conversation has a list of actions `A -> A.1 -> A.1.1`, this is the `actions group`; I need to know the count of the `actions group`.

Comment: I would suggest you ditch the aggregation and write a full script yourself. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-painless.html

Comment: Thanks, a lot! This was the way I resolved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the `scripted_metric` of elastic. Also, the `index` was changed from the initial state.

The script:

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
        "intentPathsCountAgg": {
            "scripted_metric": {
                "init_script": "state.messagesList = new ArrayList();",
                "map_script": "long currentMessageTime = doc['messageReceivedEvent.context.timestamp'].value.millis; Map currentMessage = ['conversationId': doc['messageReceivedEvent.context.conversationId.keyword'], 'time': currentMessageTime, 'intentsPath': doc['brainQueryRequestEvent.brainQueryRequest.user_data.intentsHistoryPath.keyword'].value]; state.messagesList.add(currentMessage);",  
                "combine_script": "return state",
                "reduce_script": "List messages = new ArrayList(); Map conversationsMap = new HashMap(); Map intentsMap = new HashMap(); String[] ifElseWorkaround = new String[1]; for (state in states) { messages.addAll(state.messagesList);} messages.stream().forEach((message) -> { Map existingMessage = conversationsMap.get(message.conversationId); if(existingMessage == null || message.time > existingMessage.time) { conversationsMap.put(message.conversationId, ['time': message.time, 'intentsPath': message.intentsPath]); } else { ifElseWorkaround[0] = ''; } }); conversationsMap.entrySet().forEach(conversation -> { if (intentsMap.containsKey(conversation.getValue().intentsPath)) { long intentsCount = intentsMap.get(conversation.getValue().intentsPath) + 1; intentsMap.put(conversation.getValue().intentsPath, intentsCount); } else {intentsMap.put(conversation.getValue().intentsPath, 1L);} }); return intentsMap.entrySet().stream().map(intentPath -> [intentPath.getKey().toString(): intentPath.getValue()]).collect(Collectors.toSet()) "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Formatted script (for better readability - using .ts):

```
scripted_metric: {
  init_script: 'state.messagesList = new ArrayList();',
  map_script: `
    long currentMessageTime = doc['messageReceivedEvent.context.timestamp'].value.millis;
    Map currentMessage = [
      'conversationId': doc['messageReceivedEvent.context.conversationId.keyword'],
      'time': currentMessageTime,
      'intentsPath': doc['brainQueryRequestEvent.brainQueryRequest.user_data.intentsHistoryPath.keyword'].value
    ];
    state.messagesList.add(currentMessage);`,
  combine_script: 'return state',
  reduce_script: `
    List messages = new ArrayList();
    Map conversationsMap = new HashMap();
    Map intentsMap = new HashMap();
    boolean[] ifElseWorkaround = new boolean[1];

    for (state in states) {
      messages.addAll(state.messagesList);
    }

    messages.stream().forEach(message -> {
      Map existingMessage = conversationsMap.get(message.conversationId);
      if(existingMessage == null || message.time > existingMessage.time) {
        conversationsMap.put(message.conversationId, ['time': message.time, 'intentsPath': message.intentsPath]);
      } else {
        ifElseWorkaround[0] = true;
      }
    });

    conversationsMap.entrySet().forEach(conversation -> {
      if (intentsMap.containsKey(conversation.getValue().intentsPath)) {
        long intentsCount = intentsMap.get(conversation.getValue().intentsPath) + 1;
        intentsMap.put(conversation.getValue().intentsPath, intentsCount);
      } else {
        intentsMap.put(conversation.getValue().intentsPath, 1L);
      }
    });

    return intentsMap.entrySet().stream().map(intentPath -> [
      'path': intentPath.getKey().toString(),
      'count': intentPath.getValue()
    ]).collect(Collectors.toSet())`
```

The answer:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 11,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "intentPathsCountAgg": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "smallTalk.greet -> smallTalk.greet2 -> smallTalk.greet3": 2
                },
                {
                    "smallTalk.greet -> smallTalk.greet2 -> smallTalk.greet3  -> smallTalk.greet4": 1
                },
                {
                    "smallTalk.greet -> smallTalk.greet2": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using script in  [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) we can create buckets on first character of "context.action". Using similar terms sub aggregation
we can get all the "context.action" under parent bucket ex A-> A.1->A.1.1 ...

Query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "conversations": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "def term=doc['context.action'].value; return term.substring(0,1);" 
--->  returns first character ex A,B,C etc
        },
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sub_conversations": {
          "terms": {
            "script": {
              "source": "if(doc['context.action'].value.length()>1) return doc['context.action'];"--> All context.action under [A], length check to ignore [A]
            },
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "script": {
              "source": "if(doc['context.action'].value.length()>1) return doc['context.action'];"--> count of all context.action under A
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since in elastic search it not possible to join different documents. you will have to get combined key in client side by iterating over the aggregation bucket.

Result:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "conversations" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "A",
          "doc_count" : 6,
          "sub_conversations" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "A.1",
                "doc_count" : 2
              },
              {
                "key" : "A.1.1",
                "doc_count" : 2
              }
            ]
          },
          "count" : {
            "value" : 2
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "B",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "sub_conversations" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "B.1",
                "doc_count" : 1
              }
            ]
          },
          "count" : {
            "value" : 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is not really what I need. Because of performance, I need to get almost the complete result from elasticsearch.

Comment: I managed to have a partial result for my problem, but still, there is one issue. Please check this post, in case you have any idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662222